# How to generate a sequence of random integers less than a number in Scala?

Tags: scala

The task is to write a function that generates given number of integers that are not bigger than another given number. The code I've got now looks like that:

```
scala>   def lotto(count: Int, max: Int): Seq[Int] = {
     |     var result = Seq[Int]();
     |     var x: Int = 0;
     |     for(x <- 1 to count){
     |       result = scala.util.Random.nextInt(max) :+ result
     |     }
     |   }
<console>:13: error: value :+ is not a member of Int
             result = scala.util.Random.nextInt(max) :+ result
                                                     ^
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Seq[Int]
           for(x <- 1 to count){
                 ^
```

It doesn't compile as you can see. Can someone please explain what's wrong here?

Comment: use +:, the right-associative operator.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to declare `var x` -- the `x` inside `for(x <- 1 to count)` is a _different_ `x` than the one you declared. Also, if you use `for`/`yield` you can turn `result` into a `val`.

Comment: Remove the `var x: Int = 0;`, you don't need to declare a variable, and in fact it is not even used in the loop as Daniel says. Also, get rid of the semi-colons, you don't need them in Scala.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of things as the compiler states.

`:+` should be applied to `result`. `:+` is method on `Seq`. Calling it the way you did tries to call it on `Int` which does not exist as the error says. Short story is to swap the order as shown below.

Scala returns the last value in a method. So, add `result` to the end as a return value.

```
def lotto(count: Int, max: Int): Seq[Int] = {
  var result = Seq[Int]();
  var x: Int = 0;
  for(x <- 1 to count){
    result = result :+ scala.util.Random.nextInt(max) 
  }
  result
}
```

Run it:

```
scala> lotto(10, 100)
res0: Seq[Int] = List(41, 75, 80, 80, 33, 44, 3, 24, 20, 28)
```

A more concise version of a mutable for comprehension would be to use `fill`

```
Seq.fill(count)((scala.math.random * max).toInt)
```

Or even:

```
Seq.fill(count)(util.Random.nextInt(max))
```

Answer (score 3):

A more idiomatic way to write this is the following:

```
def lotto(count: Int, max: Int): Seq[Int] =
  for (x <- 1 to count) yield scala.util.Random.nextInt(max)
```

When you program in a functional programming style, avoid mutable data (`var`).